# Numpy (np.unique) is taking up so much of space and time for very large arrays, any efficient alternative?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, point-clouds

I am using Numpy to do some downsampling processing on a pointcloud file. During this process I am using np.unique to get unique value counts from the array. This is a very large array mind you, with around 36 million 3-D points.
Is there any other efficient alternative I can use? Or any other data structure I should shift to to do exactly what np.unique is doing here to make the process faster? Right now it takes around 300 seconds. I get that unique is already optimized, but is there any alternate data structure I could use to get a better result ? The array just contains points in x,y,z format.

I am attaching a snippet of my code below. Thanks in advance for the help, and please feel free to ask me any other information you might need. I tried changing the precision level, with no effect. I am using numpy 1.24.4 on Ubuntu 22.04.

```
import numpy as np
import time

points = np.random.random(size = (38867362,3))*10000

# print(points)
# print("points bytes:",points.nbytes)

start_time = time.time()
unique_points, inverse, counts = np.unique(((points - np.min(points, axis=0)) // 3).astype(int), axis=0, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
print("::INFO:: Total time taken: ", time.time()-start_time)
```

and so on,.

Comment: `unique` sorts the array, and checks for adjacent duplicates.  `set` like a `dict` makes a hash table; your 'points' would have to be hashable tuples (not arrays or lists).

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. An example that test only `np.unique` since that is what you want to accelerate, with a realistic data set, not some unknown things taken from a file. So a ligne `points=...`, followed by a line `np.unique`.

Comment: Hey @chrslg I just updated the code, this is repeating the same problem, it is taking about 230 seconds on this. Thanks for that. Also, while trying to accelerate this, I have to use the other return values too, so is there a better way to do this while also getting the inverse and counts?

Comment: Hey @hpaulj Thanks for the suggestion, I tried making them a set, but once I downsample the points, I am not able to get back the counts and inverse which I need later. Is that possible with a set too ?

Comment: No `set` doesn't do that.  `detaultdict` could be used to collect that kind of information.  I don't know if speed is any better.  Memory use will depend on the proportion of unique values.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj I will look into `defaultdict` .

Comment: Is that Numpy array **exactly** representative in scale and dtype of the array you are using? Or can you use integers, or scaled integers or rounded integers in range 0..65536?

Comment: With the `axis`, `unique` has to take some special steps to create a `structured array` that it can `sort` as a 1d array.  There's a `note` in the docs describing the process.  That's not a trivial step, either in terms of time or memory use (even thought numpy tries to use `views` as much as possible)..  I made a test run, and then realized it would take forever.  Even so the keyboardInerrupt took some time to resolve.

Comment: You reduce `points` to an array of integers.  Even that's not a trivial task, given this array size.  Trying `unique` on single 1d arrays of numbers, such as one column, or the sum of the columns, shows it runs much faster, with unique values in the 10000 or less.  But how many unique values are then when you work with all three?

Comment: Even turning the array into a list of tuples tbat can be hashed is a long task.

Comment: I added the run time of `set()` plus the conversion to tuples to my answer. It is surprisingly fast

Comment: Hey @hpaulj Thanks for all the support. So with all three, the unique values come up to around 957304 points. Getting to this has been the slowest part. After that my process becomes easy. So basically what I am trying to do here is round off these floating point co ordinates to the nearest integer and then find the mean of the points whose round off coods are same. That is why I need to inverse and the counts

Comment: Thanks @Klops Yes making it a set is much easier, but I need the inverse because I need to reconstruct the parent array to find means later in my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to OP's ultimate goal, this is a solution for 1-D data (its easy to adjust, it was simply unclear if every dimensions is treated separately or at once).

```
from collections import defaultdict
from tqdm import tqdm  # for nice loop animations
import numpy as np

floats = np.random.random(size=(388)) * 100
ints = floats.astype(np.int32)

D = defaultdict(list)

for f, i in tqdm(zip(floats, ints), total=len(floats)):
    D[i].append(f)

means = []
for key, vals in D.items():
    means.append(np.mean(vals))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to create a set from your data. The elements of your set wont have any duplicates.

```
data = [1,1,2,3]
s = set(data)
print(len(s))
```

However, I have not tested if this is faster than your approach. Also, this won't give you the other return values of `np.unique()`.

**Edit**

As OP gave an example I measured the runtime for (1) `np.unique`, (2) conversion to list of tuple and (3) the `set()`

```
import numpy as np
import time

points = np.random.random(size = (38867362, 3)) * 10000
points = ((points - np.min(points, axis=0)) // 3).astype(int)

start_time = time.time()
unique_points, inverse, counts = np.unique(points, axis=0, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
print("::INFO:: Total time taken np.unique: ", time.time() - start_time)

start_time = time.time()
points = tuple(map(tuple, points))
print("::INFO:: Total time tuple conversion: ", time.time() - start_time)

points = tuple(map(tuple, points))
start_time = time.time()
unique_points = set(points)
print("::INFO:: Total time taken set: ", time.time() - start_time)
```

with output

```
::INFO:: Total time taken np.unique:  115.49143147468567
::INFO:: Total time tuple conversion:  36.052345991134644
::INFO:: Total time taken set:  9.044668436050415
```

So `set()` is indeed an option, if the other return values can be lost...

Comment: Yeah, making it a set was also my first thought, but I needed the other return values too for the processing in later stages.. Thank you though. I will try to push making it a set and getting the other values somehow else !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that uses pandas `DataFrame.drop_duplicates`. This is nice since it does no need a tuple conversion as `set()` would.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import pandas as pd

points = np.random.random(size = (38867362, 3)) * 10000
points = ((points - np.min(points, axis=0)) // 3).astype(int)

df = pd.DataFrame(points)

start_time = time.time()
df.drop_duplicates()
print("::INFO:: Total time taken by drop_duplicates: ", time.time() - start_time)
```

output is

```
::INFO:: Total time taken by drop_duplicates:  10.315263986587524
```

which is 4 times faster than `set()` plus tuple conversion!

**Note** `df.drop_duplicates(...).index` are a subset of the input indices an thus comparable.

Comment: This seems to be a good option, so lets say I link each rounded off int coord to it's parent float cood, would I be able to average out the points which have equal rounded off coods?

Comment: Am I correct: You have 3D float points. Then you make each dimensions smallest value zero. Than you make a true divide operation `// 3` and cast those natural numbers from float to int. Now you ask if there is a way to delete the floats from step 0 if they have a duplicate in the last step? Could you elaborate what your broader goal is? Maybe there are shortcuts (edit: i found your comment explaining your goal)